# Howe can I add alphanumeric data labels to a series in a scatter chart by openpyxl?

Tags: label, openpyxl

I have an Excel table like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 7 |
| b | 3 | 4 |
| c | 6 | 2 |

I created a scatter chart by openpyxl by using column C for values and column B for xvalues. I would like to use column A for alphanumeric data labels for points, but I cannot find a way. If I write

series_data = xl.chart.series.Series(yVal=series_y, xVal=series_x, dLbls=data_labels)

I get an error because openpyxl expect labels to be integers. Any idea why? Here is a full working code...

```
import openpyxl as xl
# Create workbook and data sheet
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Data"
# Prepare data
headers = ["Labels", "X values", "Y values"]
data = [["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], [12, 23, 34, 45, 56], [65, 45, 38, 92, 17]]
# Write data in sheet
for col in range(1, 4):
    ws.cell(row=1, column=col).value = headers[col - 1]
    for row in range(2, 7):
        ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = data[col - 1][row - 2]

# Select data for chart
mr = ws.max_row
chart_title = "Scatter chart"
chart_ref_x = xl.chart.Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_row=mr) # X values
chart_ref_y = xl.chart.Reference(ws, min_col=3, min_row=2, max_row=mr) # Y values
chart_ref_l = xl.chart.Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=mr) # Data labels

# Make scatter chart
scatter_chart = xl.chart.ScatterChart()
scatter_chart.title = chart_title
scatter_chart.x_axis.title = "X values"
scatter_chart.y_axis.title = "Y values"
scatter_chart.legend = None
# Create series
series_data = xl.chart.Series(values= chart_ref_y, xvalues= chart_ref_x)
series_data.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True
series_data.marker = xl.chart.marker.Marker('diamond')
series_data.marker.size = 8

# Add labels to series from chart_ref_l
# *** WHAT I WANT IS TO ADD "A", "B", "C", etc... as labels to chart points... but HOW? ***

# Add series to chart
scatter_chart.series.append(series_data)
# Create chartsheet and add chart
chart_sheet = wb.create_chartsheet(title="Scatter chart")
chart_sheet.add_chart(scatter_chart)
# Save workbook
wb.save("labels.xlsx")
# Close it
wb.close()
```

What I need is to undestand how to create data labels for the points in scatter chart whose values are in column 1 (chart_ref_l).

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using xlsxwriter. I couldn't find a way to do this with openpyxl.

If the below sample code in the link is not working, try updating your xlsxwriter package to the latest since the functionality was added somewhat recently.

[xlsxwriter custom data label](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html#chart-series-option-custom-data-labels)

Comment: Please include the code in your answer, not a link to it.

Please consider if this actually answers the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).